# Question about iframe and cookies how can i add the samesite none part to my cookie?

Tags: iframe, samesite

right up front I am not a professional developer and therefore ask the question to the community. I want to use the login of a website via iframe but have the problem that the cookies of the page are not accepted or forwarded and the login does not work. I have already spent a few hours looking for a solution and narrowed down the problem as follows.

If I set cookies flags in Chrome SameSite by default the login works perfectly even in the iframe. So I assume that the corresponding cookies are not accepted. I also found the cookies in the code, but I don't manage to insert the SameSite=None; Secure tag in the code.

here is the code of the cookie: (PS: I did not write the code).

```
private function _set_authentication_cookies($user_id, $remember = false, $path = '/') {
        global $db, $system, $date;
        /* generate new token */
        $session_token = get_hash_token();
        /* secured cookies */
        $secured = (get_system_protocol() == "https")? true : false;
        /* set authentication cookies */
        if($remember) {
            $expire = time()+2592000;
            setcookie($this->_cookie_user_id, $user_id, $expire, $path, "", $secured, true);
            setcookie($this->_cookie_user_token, $session_token, $expire, $path, "", true);
        } else {
            setcookie($this->_cookie_user_id, $user_id, 0, $path, "", $secured, true);
            setcookie($this->_cookie_user_token, $session_token, 0, $path, "", $secured, true);
```

and here the iframe with which the login is included:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" class="empty" src="https://domain" width=1300 height=750 onload="HandleLocationChange(this, this.contentWindow.location.href)" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-same-origin" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me, I just can't get any further....

Comment: Hi Mark, did you solve the problem?